# Posting facebook in new thread with Graph Api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

In my project user can post texts. I implemented a feaure "post also facebook" (like twitter)
Process is  I save user text in my db then try to send it to facebook with graph api..
At the end I return json response.

Pseudo code is like ;

```
db->query("insert text on USER_TEXT") 
facebookApi->status(text);
response->json(text);
```

Problem is I get json response so slow because sometimes facebook api is slow. I just want to use facebook api is a back process. So my application return response successfully asap it saved on db.
At this point share on facebook is trivial so It can be completed later.
Maybe thread based solution works for this but I dont know how it can be implemented in script language like PHP.

Maybe another simple way?

Thanks.

Comment: have you thought about Ajax. You can process the facebook operations in ajax call

Comment: Request comes from iphone. what do you mean, divide it two seperate request? One for savin on my db and then share it on facebook with another request?

Comment: Yes. something like that. You can do the facebook related expensive operations in an ajax call. Since your time consuming operations will run asynchronously it won't stop your main application. You can carry out your normal operations. Once ajax call is completed you can call a callback then.

Comment: it's ok but i want it as an atomic operation. Anyway if i cant find any other way, I can implement it. Thanks :)